# How do I make PHP throw an error if I write __constructor by mistake instead of __construct?

Tags: php

of course that was a typo and it took me longer time than expected to detect this typo. Because it's not easy sometimes to catch this simplest form of bugs.

Comment: Use autocomplete of IDE to write your code.

Comment: I can more or less guarantee that you will not write `__constructor` instead of `__construct` again. Mistakes tend to differ and this ONE is likely to happen once every leap-year (or less frequent than that). You should (like other people have suggested already) get a hold of a great IDE that makes these bugs as easy to spot as possible.

Comment: A quick comment on the questions you've posted recently (that are now deleted)... The reason those got downvoted is because it they were very general questions and [are not on-topic for StackOerflow (please take the time to read this)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  There's a lot of good information out there if you just search for it.  If while you're trying to implement something and have a specific issue, that would be a good question to post here. (I did not downvote you, btw).

Comment: Also, deleting questions (rather than fixing them) will eventually cause your account to lose the ability to post any new questions.. so watch out for that.  Based on your profile, you have answered quite a few things on here so you should have a fairly good idea about what kind of questions are appropriate.

Comment: @gloomy.penguin: Your feedback to me was very informative.I think I am much better in answering questions. By the way thank you.

Comment: @gloomy.penguin : Also your feedback gives me an indication that I need to read stackoverflow guideline and rules at-least one time!Thanks for pointing out that.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!method_exists('MyClass', '__construct') {
    die('You\'ve mis-named __construct() again.');
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php

Answer (score 1):

Use an IDE that highlights PHP errors. Personally, I like PHPStorm.

Comment: There is no syntax errors.

Comment: PHPStorm is not free.

Comment: I didn't say it's free, I said I like it :-)